# I've been banned from reviewing for some strange reason

Tags: discussion

I reviewed "First Answers" and selected "Looks OK" for two answers that look really OK to me.

https://askubuntu.com/review/first-answers/1272716

https://askubuntu.com/review/first-answers/1272761

I noticed that these answers had been deleted by **andrew.46**. There is no comment on why the questions have been deleted.

They may be incorrect, but the "First Answers" review doesn't require from a reviewer to check if every answer is correct. We check if it is a real answer and if quality is OK enough to leave the answer.

Other users can vote up or down depending on if a question is correct or not.

These review tasks look weird to me.

Comment: fyi see https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20209/announcement-ai-generated-content-temporarily-banned-on-ask-ubuntu - the specific posts you address for review tasks are bot generated and fall under the chatgpt ban - you just happened to review posts that hadn't flushed out the queue yet but were torched under the temporary ban.

Comment: How do I know they are bot generated?

Comment: Suspension from the review queue has been reversed now.

Comment: @jokerdino Thank you!

Comment: @Pilot6 Normally I ensure that I leave a comment when a post is removed but this has obviously slipped with the AI posts. My apologies that you were crunched by the system, this was completely inadvertent!

Comment: @andrew.46 No problem. I suspected it to be an AI post, but after a discussion I thought that flagging it was not necessary if I am not sure.

Comment: I have now retrospectively added a comment to all the AI posts I have deleted and will add the same to all future deletions.

Comment: @andrew.46 It is good, but does not help much. Review audits hide comments. I already missed another one.

Comment: A bit scary too, I am afraid enough to make a err while reviewing :o

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an unfortunate collission between the queues not being cleared and bot-content bans.

The system imposed a temporary 2 day review ban due to assuming this was robo-reviewing.  And in reality, it isn't but you ended up in this odd race condition case where a post was reviewed but was already deleted as violation of rules.

I can't remove the system imposed suspension on my end (maybe something's blocked...) but Jokerdino has unsuspended you from review.

Comment: And as I remember these type of bans can be lifted by a mod. Did it change?

Comment: @Pilot6 I was just in the system it did not give me the offer to remove it in the new UI here.  Joker removed your ban though.