# A user deletes their answer and posts the same question as a new post and self answers

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

*I am not sure whether I should write this on MSE or MAU, but here I go anyway*

**Context:** Couple of months ago, I came across a dearly interesting question related to corrupted desktop environments (*unfortunately,* [one of these](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5776/what-to-do-with-questions-whose-op-hasnt-visited-the-site-for-a-long-time)). The question was answered fairly well by a user "X" who had about 500 reputation (the answer wasn't accepted and had only one or two upvotes, but was factually right and well formatted).

Lately, I happened upon the same post and noticed that, that answer had been deleted by the user. Upon further investigation, I discovered that a different question with an identical body to the former question has been posted by them and self-answered with the exact same answer and have got a reasonable amount of upvotes on the question as well as the answer.

---

I could be wrong with my assumption, but the main objective is to know what stops a user from doing what is aforementioned OR if it is allowed/encouraged to do the same on SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would assume this is an extremely rare scenario.

Second, if the answering user reposts another users question without any modification, this would be considered blatant [plagiarism](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19789/what-is-the-policy-for-dealing-with-plagiarism).

However, if the answering user asks a similar question in a way that's not plagiarism, posts it and answers, then technically that's within the rules (but possibly prone to duplicate closure etc.).

It could still be argued that this isn't a very ethical way to act, and under all circumstances it should be flagged for further attention by the moderation team.

Comment: Even if they did modify it, as the original content was CC-BY-SA, they'd have to provide attribution even when creating a derivative work, or they'd be in violation of the license.

Comment: I've changed the wording to "asks a similar question in a way that's not plagiarism" - because this will surely be possible.

Comment: I assume you do not mean linking to another user's answer using the **Share button** is Plagiarism. The Share button gives full credit to the person who originally posted the solution.

Comment: That was neither what I wrote, nor what I meant ..

Answer (score 5):

Flag it - linking the other post, ideally.

It's unfair to the user who posted the answer to the original post - and it's probably worth a mod taking a look.